# How to replace multiple string at a time

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am using following codes repeatedly. Is there any better alternative.

```
Dim strtxt as string
strtxt = Replace(strtxt, "String1", "")
strtxt = Replace(strtxt, "String2", "")
strtxt = Replace(strtxt, "String3", "")
strtxt = Replace(strtxt, "String4", "")
strtxt = Replace(strtxt, "String5", "")
strtxt = Replace(strtxt, "String6", "")
strtxt = Replace(strtxt, "String7", "")
```

Comment: Well you aren't as that code isn't legal as there is no `)`. Your way is clear and as good as any other way.

Comment: Just forgot. Added. You could've added that.

Comment: The aim is clear code that makes clear what it is doing. Your way is great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
Dim mLBound As Long
Dim mUBound As Long
Dim mSize As Long
Dim result As String
Dim RepChars As Variant

RepChars = Array("a", "b", "c")

mLBound = LBound(RepChars)
mUBound = UBound(RepChars)

result = Range("A2").Value

For mSize = mLBound To mUBound
    result = Replace(result, CStr(RepChars(mSize)), "")
Next

Range("A3").Value = result
```

Comment: Better means less CPU Power and less lines. Any way This looks only solution right now.

Answer (score 1):

Or the Regex could be used. Example based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops).

```
Option Explicit

Sub ReplaceWithRegex()
    Dim strPattern As String
    Dim strReplace As String
    Dim regEx As Variant
    Dim strtxt As String

    Set regEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    strtxt = "String1.String2.String3.String4.String5.String6.String7.String77"
    strPattern = "(String.)" ' (String\d+) for replacing e.g. 'String77' etc.
    strReplace = ""

    With regEx
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = strPattern
    End With

    If regEx.Test(strtxt) Then
        Debug.Print regEx.Replace(strtxt, strReplace)
    Else
        MsgBox ("Not matched")
    End If
End Sub
```

[regexr](http://regexr.com/3csa0)

Answer (score 1):

One way:

```
Function RemoveTokens(target As String, ParamArray tokens() As Variant) As String
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To UBound(tokens)
        target = Replace$(target, tokens(i), "")
    Next
    RemoveTokens = target
End Function
```

---

```
?RemoveTokens("AA BB CC DD EE", "BB")
AA  CC DD EE

?RemoveTokens("AA BB CC DD EE", "BB", "EE", "AA")
  CC DD
```

Comment: I think there some mistake by SO. didn't receive notification of this answer.